# How to get a number of comments of a specific post

Tags: javascript, blogger

Is it possible to get the number of comments of a specific post blogger?

I use this code to get these values ​in total.
Instead, I need these values ​for a specific post.

```
<script>
function numberOfPosts(json) {
document.write(json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t + ' number post');
}
function numberOfComments(json) {
document.write(json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t + ' number comments)');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you need to get json feed of comments of your post by post Id (*each post has a unique id*)

```
your-blog-url/feeds/your-post-id/comments/default?alt=json
```

Then pass json to your function `numberOfComments`